# Is it possible to clear all cookies in an Android device?

Tags: android, cookies, android-webview, privacy

Many apps in Android are using embedded webviews.

Is it possible to clear the cookies set in such webviews?

If I clear the cookies from the browser menu, are the ones set by webviews cleared as well?

**EDIT:** From the [Webview documentation page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) it seems that the cookies of a webview are kept separate from the ones of the browser, hence I suspect that the user cannot delete the cookies set by a webview:

> For obvious security reasons, your application has its own cache, cookie store etc.—it does not share the Browser application's data.

Is there a way to delete them via the settings or via some other tool?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To disallow cookies from being stored in a webview, try the following by using [CookieManager](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/CookieManager.html):

```
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(false);
```

You could also remove them manually yourself:

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(false);
```

Here is the documentation:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html

And the removeAllCookie() function looks like this:

> public abstract void removeAllCookies (ValueCallback callback)